# How to append new list item to a list

Tags: docx, docx4j

I would like to find a list paragraph (starting with a. ), and append another list item to this list (it depend on the text of first list element).
I have tried many ways of creating new paragraph, but all what I achieved is that new list elements are created, but `org.docx4j.wml.Text` objects are appended to paragraph the new paragraph was appended. The new paragraph text is empty. How can be new list element created and appended to the right element?

- a. list element 1 |test|    //|test| should be appended to b.
- b.                          //new items are created, but there is no text
- c.

> ```
>   //traverse through a document
>     public List<Object> apply(Object obj) {
>        if (obj instanceof org.docx4j.wml.P) { 
>           if (p.getPPr() != null) {
>              if (p.getPPr().getPStyle() != null) {
>                 if ((p.getPPr().getPStyle().getVal().equals("Akapitzlist"))) {
>                    //there is a list paragraph
>                          ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
>                          Object deepCopy = XmlUtils.deepCopy(obj);
>                     //Create the paragraph 
>                     org.docx4j.wml.P para = factory.createP();
>
>                     // Create the text element 
>                     org.docx4j.wml.Text t = factory.createText();
>                     t.setValue("|test|");
>
>                     // Create the run 
>                     org.docx4j.wml.R run = factory.createR();
>                     run.getContent().add(t);
>                     para.getContent().add(run);
>                     //add new paragraph to the document
>                     ((org.docx4j.wml.P) obj).getContent().add(para);
>
>     }...}
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, just append to the body with incremented index. I' am creating deep copy to preserwe style.

```
    public List<Object> apply(Object obj) {


    Object deepCopy = null;



    if (obj instanceof org.docx4j.wml.P) {

        org.docx4j.wml.P p = (org.docx4j.wml.P) obj;


        if (p.getPPr() != null) {
            if (p.getPPr().getPStyle() != null) {
                if ((p.getPPr().getPStyle().getVal().equals("Akapitzlist")) && (akapListCounter < 10)) {

                    if (((org.docx4j.wml.P) obj).getPPr().getPStyle() != null) {
                        if ((((org.docx4j.wml.P) obj).getPPr().getPStyle().getVal().equals("Akapitzlist"))) {
                            deepCopy = XmlUtils.deepCopy(obj);
                            akapListCounter++;
                            int indexOf = wmlDocumentEl.getBody().getContent().indexOf(obj);


                            List<Object> content = ((org.docx4j.wml.P) deepCopy).getContent();
                            for (Object el : content) {
                                System.out.println("class1:" + el.getClass().toString());
                                if (el instanceof org.docx4j.wml.R) {
                                    List<Object> subc = ((org.docx4j.wml.R) el).getContent();
                                    for (Object r : subc) {
                                        ((javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) r).setValue("tetetete");
                                    }
                                }

                            }// end for


                            wmlDocumentEl.getBody().getContent().add(indexOf + 1, deepCopy);


                        }
                    }//end get style

                }
            } 
        } else {}


    }

    return null;
}
```